# Single GKE Ingress path with multiple wildcards

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, wildcard, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to create a path in a GKE ingress like this: /organizations/''/entity/''/download.

NOTE: The '' above represents a wildcard (*)

The values after organizations/ and after entity/ are dynamic so I have to use two  wildcards, but this is not working, the first wildcard after the /organizations/* is taking all the requests.

I want to apply a different timeout only on this specific request, therefore I need to configure it just like this, if there is /test instead of /download at the end, it shouldn't take place.

I can't be the only one to have the same situation, and I am struggling to find anything on internet with the same issue?
Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The only supported wildcard character for the path field of an Ingress is the * character. The * character must follow a forward slash (/) and must be the last character in the pattern. For example, /*, /foo/*, and /foo/bar/* are valid patterns, but *, /foo/bar*, and /foo/*/bar are not.

Source (From GKE Ingress docs): https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services